# WSO2 Idenity Server - How to validate an OIDC Bearer Token in JWT Format

Tags: wso2, jwt, identity, wso2-identity-server

What is the recommended solution to validate a JSON Web Token (jwt) id-token at a secondary server that delivers REST/JSON based API services. For design also consider performance aspects:

- To validate the trusted issuer and signature contained in the jwt, as
  well as its expiry (check "nbf" to "exp" window), avoiding repeated lookups at the WSO2 
  IdP?
- To submit the jwt (or access token) sending it to the IdP doing a  revalidation at each API request?
- To improve security by adding an encryption layer (JWE) with an asymmetric algorithm and use of a shared public key (RSA)?
- Other validation methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for option #1. ie. Validate trusted issuer's signature and other validations as specified in [1]

If we go for option #2 how are we going to validate the response received  after validation? If we are using signature or encryption then it's a waste of an extra call.

A combination of #1 and #3 would be ideal. But that would certainly have an impact on performance.

[1] http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation